# Проблемы с отправкой изображения на сервер

Tags: c#, uwp

До сих пор пытаюсь разобраться с проблемой отправки изображения на хостинг.
По большей части, работаю методом тыка. Вот что натыкал в приложении:

```
{
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker(); //Открываю изображение
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
                {

                    //преобразую поток в байтовый массив
                    byte[] fileBytes;
                    using (var Stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
                    {
                        var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Stream);
                        fileBytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)Stream.Length);
                    }

                    using (var client = new HttpClient())
                    {

                        var apiUri = new Uri("Некий.Хостинг.php");

                        var imageBinaryContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);

                        var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                        multipartContent.Add(imageBinaryContent, "image" );

                        var result = await client.PostAsync(apiUri, multipartContent);
                        Name.Text = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Name.Text = "Operation cancelled.";
        }
    }
```

Код php файла на сервере:

`<?php
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
$filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
// Decode Image
$binary=base64_decode($base);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$file = fopen("uploads/".$filename, 'wb');
// Create File
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
echo 'Image upload complete, Please check your php file directory';
?>`

Но файлик не доходит до места назначения... Помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На помощь пришел этот вопрос. Все заработало. Осталось разобрать код :-)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425043/upload-image-using-httpclient

---

Если не трудно, проверьте мое понимание этого кода:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();   //создаем клиент который используется для приема и передачи данных
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://your.url.com/"); //Адрес по которому будет искаться необходимый php файл
        MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent(); // Нечто вроде посылки которая умеет вмешать в себя несколько любых объектов 
        HttpContent content = new StringContent("fileToUpload"); // Зачем то создается этот контент с таким именем...
        form.Add(content, "fileToUpload"); //мы запихивием этот "fileToUpload" в двух экземплярах? В виде переменной и просто текста?
        var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync(); //Создаем поток для передачи
        content = new StreamContent(stream); // "Включаем его"
        content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") // Создаем с какой-то целью заголовок в котором имя файла и опять "fileToUpload"
        {
            Name = "fileToUpload",
            FileName = file.Name
        };
        form.Add(content); //Еще раз добавляем в посылку
        var response = await client.PostAsync("upload.php", form); //Отправляем
        return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; //Ждем ответа
```